# Converting Hash to String using first 8 characters of the Hash

Tags: hash

I have a set of hashes with only first 8 characters of it.

How can I identify the string for that hash? A software which I used uses SHA-1 Algorithm to define short names for fonts where it uses only first 8 characters of the hash.

So I need to get what are all the hashes starts with those 8 characters.

Comment: loop and `regex`

Comment: Can you explain in detail